# Showing Linear Independence of $\, \{e^x, \, e^{-x}\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

We examine the equation

$$ae^x + be^{-x} = 0$$

My book say manipulate to get

$$ae^{2x} = -b$$

and "The two members are identical for all $x$ only if

$$a =b = 0 \, \text{ "}$$

[Therefore the set in the title is L.I.]

---

My confusion is that I can easily choose $a = 2, b = -3$ and find an $x$ where the equation is satisfied. I can repeat this process for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The definition my book uses for L.I. is

> A set of functions  \begin{equation}  \{y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n\}
>  \end{equation} defined on $(a,b)$ is *linearly independent* if the
>    linear combination for the set  \begin{equation} c_1y_1+c_2y_2 +
>  \cdots + c_ny_n = 0 \end{equation} implies that for all $x$ the only solution is 
>    \begin{equation} c_1= c_2=\cdots =c_n = 0 \end{equation}

I'm guessing that means the $c_i$ must be fixed, and that's where I'm wrong. I don't see anything in the definition saying that $c_i$ must be fixed, nor anywhere I look; is it implied? The nature of the definition hints that there might be more than one solution depending on the function set (making the set L.D.), which to me means that the set of constants does not have to be fixed.

Comment: The $c_i$ are indeed supposed to be scalars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $c_i$ do have to be fixed: since we're talking about linear independence of the set of functions, we're looking for a linear combination of functions that add to the **zero function**, i.e., the function which returns zero for all $x$. This function is fixed by fixed constants $c_i$. I agree that the definition you posted is a bit unclear on this point.

Comment: I was about to write this, there is an important distinction between zeroes and the zero function. In this case, the zero vector in our vector space is the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

The equality $$ae^{2x}+b=0$$ should be true for all value of $x$.

From here we indeed obtain that $a=b=0.$

Answer (score 1):

The most important part here is to understand what the symbol $0$ actually means. It depends on the context.

You might be talking about the number $0_{\mathbb{R}} \in \mathbb{R}$ or the matrix $0_{\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}} := \begin{pmatrix}0_{\mathbb{R}}&0_{\mathbb{R}}\\0_{\mathbb{R}}&0_{\mathbb{R}}\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ or the map $0_{\operatorname{map}} \in \{ f \mid f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \}$, where $0_{\operatorname{map}}(x) = 0_\mathbb{R}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

In your case it could help to just rewrite the problem a bit. Let's say $f(x) := e^x$ and $g(x) := e^{-x}$. This way we can easily talk about **maps** (i.e. $f$) and **images** (i.e. $f(x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Now you need to check $a f + b g = 0$. Since we are using the **maps** (instead of the images), the $0$ is actually itself a map (see $0_{\operatorname{map}}$ from above). So we are "comparing" maps to eachother. (i.e. the [linear combined] map on the left-handside is the same as the map on the right-handside)

The map on the right-handside yields (by definition) $0_{\operatorname{map}}(x) = 0_{\mathbb{R}}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. So what are all possible values for $a$ and $b$ such that

\begin{align*} 
&\hphantom{\Leftrightarrow}& af + bg &= 0_{\operatorname{map}} &\\ 
&\Leftrightarrow& af(x) + bg(x) &= 0_{\operatorname{map}}(x) &\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow& a e^x + b e^{-x} &= 0_\mathbb{R} &\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& a e^x e^x + b e^{-x} e^{x} &= 0_\mathbb{R} \cdot e^{x} &\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& a e^{2x} + b &= 0_\mathbb{R} &\forall x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

is valid **for all** $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Let's check under what circumstances the **maps** match by looking at the **images**.

If we pick $a = 0_\mathbb{R} = b$, the images (and so the maps itself) obviously match for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We do also notice that $a = 0_\mathbb{R} \Leftrightarrow b = 0_\mathbb{R}$.

So let's assume $a \neq 0_\mathbb{R} \neq b$. Now let's test if the maps match on certain values for $x$. For example $x=0_\mathbb{R}$, $x=1$ or any other value. We notice $a e^{2 \cdot 0_\mathbb{R}} + b = a + b \overset{!}{=} 0_\mathbb{R}$, so $a = -b$. Alright, we can use this from now on (and will call it **(1)**), since it needs to be valid regardless of what $x$ we pick. Now let's plug-in $x=1$. We get $a e^{2 \cdot 1} + b = a e^2 + b \overset{!}{=} 0_\mathbb{R}$, so $a e^2 = -b$ and by **(1)** we get $a e^2 = a \Leftrightarrow e^2 = 1$, since $a \neq 0_\mathbb{R}$. Well, $e^2 = 1$ does not look right.

This leaves us no other choice than stick to $a = 0_\mathbb{R} = b$ to make sure that the **maps** match (for all of their **images**).

Answer (score 0):

I think your primary confusion is that $ae^x+be^{-x}=0$ does mean for fixed values of $a,~b.$ That is, you cannot choose $a,~b$ for each $x.$ You must find fixed $a,~b$ which makes the equation true, for all $x\in\Bbb{R}.$ That leaves you with only $a=b=0.$

Answer (score -1):

Take natural logarithm from both sides of equality $ae^x=-be^{-x}$, then you can see that $x$ should be $\frac{ln(a)+ln(-b)}{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose
$$
                  a e^x+be^{-x} = 0, \;\; x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
The differential operator $(\frac{d}{dx}+1)$ annihilates $e^{-x}$ and gives $2e^x$ when applied to $e^{x}$, which leads to
$$
                         2ae^x  = 0 \implies a=0.
$$
Hence, $be^{-x}=0$ also holds, which forces $b=0$ as well. So $\{ e^x,e^{-x} \}$ is a linearly independent set of functions on $\mathbb{R}$.